# How To Delete File from FTP

Tags: java, ftp

Can anyone please suggest how to delete a file from FTP server. I don't want to use Apache FTP Client.

For FTP connection and downloading file from FTP i am using below code:

```
URL url = new URL("ftp://"+userName+":"+password+"@"+url12+"/"+folderLocation+";type=i");
        URLConnection urlc = url.openConnection();
        InputStream is = urlc.getInputStream();                                             
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));

        String line = null;
        try {
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {

                if ( line.endsWith(".dat")) {
                    String fileName = getFileNameFromFTP(line, file_Name);

                    if ( ! TCUtility.isStringNullOrEmpty(fileName)){

                        File file = download(url12,userName,password, folderLocation+"/"+fileName);

                        if ( file != null) {
                            fileList.add(file);
                        }                   
                    }               
                }
            }
            urlc.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Close");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            ex = e;
        } finally {
            try {
                is.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                ex = e;
            }

            if ( ex != null )
                throw ex;
        }
```

---

public File download( String ftpServer, String user, String password,
            String fileName ) throws MalformedURLException,
            IOException 
            {
        if (ftpServer != null && fileName != null)
        {
            File file = File.createTempFile("TempDoc", ".dat");

```
        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer( "ftp://" );
        // check for authentication else assume its anonymous access.
        if (user != null && password != null)
        {
            sb.append( user );
            sb.append( ':' );
            sb.append( password );
            sb.append( '@' );
        }
        sb.append( ftpServer );
        sb.append( '/' );
        sb.append( fileName );
        /*
         * type ==> a=ASCII mode, i=image (binary) mode, d= file directory
         * listing
         */
        sb.append( ";type=i" );
        BufferedInputStream bis = null;
        BufferedOutputStream bos = null;
        try
        {
            URL url = new URL( sb.toString() );
            URLConnection urlc = url.openConnection();

            bis = new BufferedInputStream( urlc.getInputStream() );

            bos = new BufferedOutputStream( new FileOutputStream(file ) );

            int i;
            while ((i = bis.read()) != -1)
            {

                bos.write( i );
            }
        }
        finally
        { 
            if (bis != null)
                try
            {
                    bis.close();
            }
            catch (IOException ioe)
            {
                ioe.printStackTrace();
            }
            if (bos != null)
                try
            {
                    bos.close();
            }
            catch (IOException ioe)
            {
                ioe.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return file;
    }
    return null;
        }
```

Comment: why don't you want to use Apache FTP Client ? do you mean you prefer implement a simple ftp client protocol by yourself or you want to use 3rd party library (such as [ftp4j](http://www.sauronsoftware.it/projects/ftp4j/)) other than Apache FTP Client?

Comment: Actually i was getting some error while using Apache FTP Client. though it has been resolved. But just curious to know is there any other way...

Comment: Did you look at Apache FTP client's source code ?